# About the uniform norm in 2 dimensional space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm.

In particular, for the case of a vector ${\displaystyle x=(x_{1},x_2)}$ in two dimensional coordinate space, it takes the form

${\displaystyle \|x\|_{\infty }=\max\{|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|\}.}$

Why its graph is a square? As the perimeter of the square is the set of points in $R^2$ where the sup norm equals a fixed positive constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm#/media/File:Vector_norm_sup.svg

Comment: Can you solve for $x_1,x_2$ when $\max(|x_1|, |x_2|) = 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful not to get confused with what the graph is representing.  The graph is not representing the uniform norm of $x$, since the uniform norm is just a number (in $\mathbb R$).  The graph is actually that of the boundary of a closed ball in $\mathbb R^2$, centered at the origin with some radius, say $r$.  Using the uniform norm, the boundary can be represented as the set of all $(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that:
$$ \| (x_1,x_2) \|_\infty = \text{max}\{ |x_1|, |x_2| \} = r$$

In order for the max to be equal to $r$, either $|x_1| = r$ and $|x_2| \leq r$ or, $|x_2| = r$ and $|x_1| \leq r$.

This allows us to rewrite the boundary as the union of the following sets:

- $\{(-r,x_2): -r \leq x_2 \leq r\}$
- $\{(r,x_2): -r \leq x_2 \leq r\}$
- $\{(x_1,-r): -r \leq x_1 \leq r\}$
- $\{(x_1,r): -r \leq x_1 \leq r\}$

Now, drawing out all of these region on the graph will result in a square, with side length $r$.  As mentioned, this square is the boundary of the ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$ under the uniform norm.

Comment: For me (I was also confused about the figure) I was confused because the definition at the beginning of the article gives $\sup\left\{\,\left|f(x)\right|:x\in S\,\right\}$, but in the case of a vector $f$ is not the vector itself, but rather an index on the elements of the vector.